# PHP-CPP new extension works on cli 'php' command but not in browser

Tags: c++, mysql, php-extension, php-cpp

I am using PHP-CPP to create a php extension which contains a function that will parse a table from mysql.

extension.cpp

```
#include <phpcpp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql.h>

Php::Value  ss_parse_table(Php::Parameters &params)
{ 
MYSQL *conn;
MYSQL_RES *res;
MYSQL_ROW row;
MYSQL_FIELD *field;

/* INITIALIZE CONNECTION HANDLER, DO NOT CHANGE */
conn = mysql_init (NULL);


// @param orders: host,username,password,database,
mysql_real_connect (conn, params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3], 3306, NULL, 0);
/* show tables in the database (test for errors also) */


mysql_query(conn,("SELECT * FROM table");
res = mysql_store_result(conn);


// get the number of the columns
int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(res);

Php::Value array;
Php::Value rows;
int i = 0;

while((field = mysql_fetch_field(res))){
    array[i] = field->name;
    i++;
}

int x = 0;
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)))
{

    for (int z=0;z<num_fields;z++) 
    {
        std::string fieldname = array[z];
        rows[x][fieldname] = row[z];
    }

    x++;
}

// DON'T FORGET TO CLEAN RESULT AFTER YOU DON'T NEED IT 
// ANYMORE
if(res != NULL)
   mysql_free_result(res);

/* disconnect from server */
mysql_close (conn);

return rows;

}

extern "C" {


  PHPCPP_EXPORT void *get_module() 
  {
    \
    static Php::Extension extension("extension", "1.0");
    extension.add("ss_parse_table",ss_parse_table);
    // @todo    add your own functions, classes, namespaces to the extension

    // return the extension
    return extension;
  }
}
```

and in compiling I edited the MakeFile and appended `mysql_config --cflags --libs` in the compiler command in order to load mysql so it will look like `g++ -shared -o extension.so extension.o -lphpcpp mysql_config --cflags --libs` the compilation works fine.

I tried testing if the compilation really worked by using the defined function (ss_parse_table) from the extension. So I created a php file:

test.php

```
<?php
  print_r(ss_parse_table( "localhost", "dbuser","dbpassword","database"));
 ?>
```

and from the CLI when I run the command 'php /mnt/test/index.php' it works fine.
The command will output array returned by the defined extension function (ss_parse_table), something like this

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [id] => 'erd'
  )
)
```

but when I browse it from the browser the http fails

'No data received' (chrome error) or 'The connection was reset' (firefox error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. I solved this by adding the directory where my **libmysqlclient.so** file is located to the system PATH:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib64
```

and then, restarting httpd service:

```
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

After that, everything worked fine.

I hope it helps